# On select text-indent is not working in Edge, It is working in all other browser

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I am using `text-indent` on select it is working in all browser but not working in Edge. [Click here to see a JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z1hjytbb/36)

```css
    input {
    text-indent: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    }
    select {
    text-indent: 50px;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    }
```

```html
    <input value="value text-indent (50px)">
    <input placeholder="placeholder text-indent (50px)">
    <select>
    <option>sdasdasdasd</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: working fine for me in IE

Comment: @DeepakVerma issue in  IE Edage

Comment: yeh i can see it now. Is there any issue if you use padding-left in place of text-indent

Comment: Microsoft Edge is a different browser from Internet Explorer. They are not the same thing.